# Omission of prepositions with movement verbs

Tags: verbs, prepositions

The image below is a section from *A Complete Grammar of Esperanto* (Ivy Kellerman, 1910), outlining the use of accusatives with verbs expressing motion. I've marked the relevant parts in red.

[image: Excerpt]
To my knowledge, this is the first time in the book where the verb *iri* appears without a preposition (the author previously used it in conjunction with *al*, *ĝis* and *de*), and seems to be provided without explanation as to why the preposition is allowed to be omitted. I'm puzzled: **When is it appropriate to omit the preposition? And what verbs can this be done with?** (i.e., can *flugas al la nesto* be shortened to *flugas la neston*?)

For the practice sentences included in the chapter, the online third party answers do not seem to omit the preposition. For example,

> *We went to the city of Boston yesterday and into a beautiful house.*

might be translated to

> *Ni iris la urbon Bostono hieraŭ kaj en la belan domon.*

based on the example given in the book, but the answers use *iris al la urbo Bostono* instead.

I was searching for the correct way to add the accusative ending to the apposition *urbo Bostono*, and found that PMEG had a similar example to the one given in the book, which can be found [here](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/specialaj_priskriboj/identiga.html). The example PMEG gave was:

> Ni vizitis la urbon Parizo.

This is my fourth day learning Esperanto, so I can't understand PMEG yet, but 
the chapter seemed to talk only about apposition (*Identiga priskribo*). I would appreciate it if someone could find the answer to the highlighted question above from a credible source such as PMEG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accusative case is used in Esperanto for a couple of things. The most obvious one is the direct object. Another one is to show movement to a direction. Thus you can say

> *Mi veturas Varsovion.*
>
> *Ni iris la urbon Bostono.*

However many considers this way old-fashioned and contemporary way is to use a preposition

> *Mi veturas al Varsovio.*
>
> *Ni iris al la urbo Bostono.*

There is a [discussion](https://lernu.net/fr/forumo/temo/26927/1) (in Esperanto) in Lernu of some further aspects.

Lernu has a [grammar section](https://lernu.net/eo/gramatiko/akuzativo), which explains the use of the accusative. There is a language selector at the bottom of the page, if you prefer to read the explanation in another language.

Comment: PMEG trafe parolas pri -n finaĵo, ne akuzativo. En la frazo "mi iras ĝardenon" (mi neniam en mia vivo aŭdis ion tian) la -n ne rilatas objekton de ago, sed [uzon de -n por direkto](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/n/direkto.html).

Comment: PMEG uzas ne-tradicajn gramatikajn terminojn, ekz. N-finaĵon anstataŭ akuzativo. Diversaj lingvoj uzas kazojn diversmaniere. La espa uzas ĝin por montri rektan objekton, direkton ktp. Do akuzativo ≠ rekta objekto.